# App Inventor: Asynchonous tasks?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, app-inventor

Is there any way to use more than one thread in MIT App Inventor? I'm trying to keep a while loop going while the app does other things, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible, App Inventor is single threaded, see also [the model of event processing in App Inventor](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/m8i32I2m200/Am3VYo3DTIUJ) by Lyn.

You therefore should better use a `clock` component instead of a `while` loop.
See also my doSomething example

[image]